# Plotting XRD Spectra with Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to this community and python. Recently, I have been trying to plot XRD spectra of my samples via python, but i have couple of problems/questions to ask.

I have 13 different XRD spectra and I have tried to plot them in one figure with the below code in jupyter notebook. Here my questions that I could not solve appeared.

1. How can I do anti-aliasing so that my plot looks a bit better?
2. I want to add ICDD information in that graph like this [XRD Spectra drawn by Origin Pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMpMf.jpg). I could not figure out how to do this in python, so anyone can help me about this?
3. When I focus on the X values between 39.5 to 42 degrees using the same code, my XRD peaks are broadening [Broadening in XRD spectra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCHIo.jpg). I want to get more clear sharp peaks, so my question is how I can eleminate peak broadening during plotting.

I am also open for a better visualisation tool for XRD spectra if you suggest one

Thank you

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline

file_path = "X-Ray Data of Laser Remelted Buttons.xlsx"  # Replace with the actual file path
excel_data = pd.ExcelFile(file_path)
sheet_names = excel_data.sheet_names

dataframes = {}
for sheet_name in sheet_names:
    df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=sheet_name, skiprows=1)
    dataframes[sheet_name] = df

# Accessing a specific dataframe and sheet name
sheet_name = sheet_names[0]
df = dataframes[sheet_name]
print("Sheet Name:", sheet_name)
print(df.head())

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

offset = 0  # Initialize the offset

for sheet_name in sheet_names:
    data = excel_data.parse(sheet_name)
    x = df['X']  # Assuming the XRD data is in a column named "X Values"
    y = df['Y (counts)']  # Assuming the XRD data is in a column named "Y Values"
    ax.plot(x, y + offset, label=sheet_name)  # Plot the XRD data with the offset applied
    offset += max(y) - min(y)  # Update the offset based on the range of the current data


ax.set_xlabel("X Values")  # Customize the X-axis label
ax.set_ylabel("Y Values")  # Customize the Y-axis label
ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.1), ncol=3)  # Adjust the coordinates and ncol as per your preference
ax.set_title("XRD Spectra")  # Customize the plot title
ax.set_yticklabels([])
ax.set_xlim(20, 95)

#ax.grid(True)  # Add a grid to the plot

plt.show()  # Display the plot
```

Tried to plot XRd spectra for specific 2Theta angles resulting in peak broadening. I have been expecting sharper peak (no broadening)